# Breezejs SocketIO and jsonResultsAdapter

Tags: breeze, socket.io

I have a REST backend without OData and with SocketIO. Breeze datacontext is configured with a jsonResultsAdapter to create the Entities. When I start my app I call 
DataContext.manager.executeQuery(query) and every thing is working as expected... Subsequently the additional data is being pushed to the app by SocketIO. How do I pass the data to Breeze so that the 'visitNode' method in the jsonResultsAdapter is called for all the nodes of the pushed json feed?

Comment: That is such a GREAT GREAT question. I've been dying to have a really good reason to expose the Breeze entity merge api. Let me shop this internally and see what we can do.

Comment: Great, this is my work-around for the moment... I had to expose the MappingContext internal helper. var mappingContext = new MappingContext( {
                    query: null,
                    entityManager: DataContext.manager,
                    mergeOptions: { mergeStrategy: gBreeze.MergeStrategy.OverwriteChanges },
                    dataService: DataContext.manager.dataService
                });

                var res = mappingContext.visitAndMerge(data, { nodeType: "root" });